# Failed to instantiate module marbleApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: angularjs

Failed to instantiate module marbleApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'marbleApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I've read almost every post and searched through the docs, but my app won't work because my module isn't being loaded. Can anybody find any bugs in the code that keep it from working properly?

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="marbleApp">
    <head>
      <title>Marble.com AngularMongo</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>  

    </head>

    <body>

      {{"anot" + "her test"}}

      <nav style="background-color: #d56324!important">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
          <form action="/cosmicblack" method="GET">
            <div class="input-field">
              <input id="search" type="search" required placeholder="Search">
              <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
              <i class="material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <br>

      <div>
    {{"This is " + "a test!"}}
    {{materials.name}}
      </div>
    <!-- <div ng-controller="repeatCtrl">{{materials.name}}</div> -->



    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">  


        <div class="col m3" ng-controller='repeatCtrl'>
          <a href="/cosmicblack"><div class="card">
            <div class="card-image small">
                <img src="http://marble.com/uploads/materials/499/300X300/thumbnail/Cosmic-Black_APeruB9I056YsF3mZ0sT.jpg">
                <span class="card-title" ng-bind="materials.name"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>







      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


    </body>
  </html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('marbleApp', []);

app.controller('repeatCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.materials = [
        {name: 'Cosmic Black'}
    ];      
});
```

server.js:

```
console.log('May Node be with you');

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});



app.get('/cosmicblack', (req, res) => {
    var cursor = db.collection('materials').find();
    db.collection('materials').find({"id": "499"}).toArray(function(err, results) {
        console.log(results);
    });
    db.collection('materialphotos').find({"material_id": "499"}).toArray(function(err, results2) {
        console.log(results2);
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});



app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Running app.js on 3000');
});
```

Comment: Your code is working for me. I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the same code as yours, and it works for me. Take a look at this [bin](https://jsbin.com/vusonitota/1/edit?html,js,console,output). The usual cause for the `nomod` error in angular is that either `angular.js` or any of the dependencies of your app has not loaded correctly causing your app module to not load correctly

Comment: It works on the expression tests, but then when the code hits the ng-controller="repeatCtrl", which should render materials.name from the $scope object, it doesn't. Not only does it not show the name, but the expression doesn't even show up at all.

Comment: Your error was that you were trying to access `.name` from array `$scope.materials`. Try using `{{ materials[0].name }}`. I have updated the bin with same

Comment: When you run the code, are you simply opening it in Chrome? I think there may be an issue with my node.js/express server. When I run my server and go to localhost, the code doesn't work. But when I simply open it in the browser directly, it works fine. Any idea why that would be the case?